Swift md5 from image
I want convert to md5 hash my image. I have created data from image.  let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)     And i convert it with extension but appears to be different from the hash value I get from online or terminal md5 services.
extension Data {
        var md5 : String {
            var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
            _ =  self.withUnsafeBytes { bytes in
                CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
            }
            var digestHex = ""
            for index in 0..<Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
                digestHex += String(format: "%02x", digest[index])
            }
            return digestHex
        }
    }

I created this extension. But its not given correct output i guess. Can someone help me? Thanks.

This question is similar to: Swift: Calculated md5 hash of image file doesn't match with terminal and other hash generator. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Short answer: JPEG is a lossy format. Loading a JPEG into a UIImage converts the file into an in-memory image format. Accessing jpegData converts that in-memory format back to a jpeg but you won't  get the same data back out. You could load the Data from the file directly and your md5 hash would match,  it as the linked answer above suggests, the app bundle process itself may also modify image files
